# Quotes for values of html attributes

Tags: jquery, html, regex

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        $("body").append("<p id=\"element"+i+"\">Hello world, I'm Element " + i + ".<p>");
    }
});
```

Looking at the third line, what are the matching quotation mark pairs? I'm assuming the escape d quotes are one.  Also, why is +i+ surrounded with quotes? Shouldn't the escaped quotes suffice? edit:  I left out a bit of code. sorry!

Comment: What exactly do you want us to tell you here? The matching quotes are the ones made obvious by the syntax highlighter. `+i+` isn't part of the string, the unescaped quotes around it terminate the first string and begin another one after the `+i+`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I started jquery/js a few days ago and I'm struggling with regex + how quotes work. Your comment makes it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escaped quotes match each other in the HTML string that you're creating.

The quotes are not "surrounding" `+i+`. They're being used to end the string that begins with

```
"<p id=\"element"
```

and to begin the next string:

```
"\">Hello world, ..."
```

This is concatenating `i` between these two strings. So if `i` contains `0`, the resulting HTML will be

```
<p id="element0">Hello world, I'm element 0</p>
```

The escaped quotes allow the quotes to be put in the string, but you still have to get *out* of the string to expand a variable.

Javascript is not like PHP, it doesn't expand variables inside strings (because there's no special prefix like `$` that tells where a variable begins).

Answer (score 1):

**An Optical Illusion**

> Why is +i+ surrounded with quotes?

It is not. The `+` is the concatenation operator, and has the effect of inserting successive values of i between the preceding and following strings, producing things like:

- `<p id="element1">Hello...`
- `<p id="element2">Hello...`
- `<p id="element3">Hello...`
- etc.

**Also note:**

1. The `"` quote before `+i+` does not belong with `+i+`. It closes the  string opened with `"<p id`
2. `\"` is not a quotation mark that belongs to the code. Rather, it belongs to the string, and the escaping `\` is necessary so it doesn't get confused with closing or opening quotes.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an "optional illusion" when you have proper syntax highlighting.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, you're dead right. :)

Comment: this provides me even more clarity for an answer. I wish I can accept two answers :) thank you.